# How open function call phone but don't set phone number default

Tags: android, android-intent

I want open function call phone of android but don't set phone number default as

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:09340125465"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

I want to open call phone and after input phone number.

Hope you me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you know to open locked of android after end call?

Comment: Hi iturki,After End call android had locked screen, i want to open it and back to my Activity after End call.

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't do that. Once you start the Intent, you lose the control.